# Quick action property - getter only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, say I have a class field that looks like this:

```
private string name;
```

I can right-click the field and select "Quick Actions & Refactoring > Encapsulate Field", which creates a property like this:

```
public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
```

If I have a field that looks like this:

```
private readonly string name;
```

and I use quick-actions to create a property, it only creates a getter:

```
public string Name => name;
```

I sometimes have private fields that should not be read-only within the class, but should be read-only from other classes. In other words, I want this:

```
private string name;
public string Name => name;
```

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to generate a getter-only property like this when the *field* is not read-only?

Comment: I'm sure this is a special case that you should not expect to be a standard feature in VS. If this is bothering you perhaps start by creating the `readonly` field, generate the accessor and then delete the `readonly` part

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a readonly property from outside, but not readonly internal. ReadOnly means that it can only change once while being constructed. What you want is a private setter, like this: `pubilc string Name { get; private set; }`. But there is no way you can expect VS to know that that is what you want. If you like you can create your own Quick action, if this is a matter of refactoring a lot of code.

Comment: @Michael I would call `public string Name => name;` a 'read-only property' since it can only be used to read the value, regardless of whether `name` is a `readonly` field. But that's semantics.